# C# Interest on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

This [blog post](http://www.r-chart.com/2010/08/programming-language-popularity.html) analyzed stack overflow tags and indicates that C# is highly represented (perhaps disproportionately so).  Other than the obvious explanation that there just happen to be a bunch of C# programmers interested in the site - what accounts for this statistic?

Comment: John Skeet 15ch

Comment: @Tom - I don't get the '15ch' part!

Comment: @Jay - comments have to be at least 15 characters long. "John Skeet" is 10 so @Tom needed to add another 5 characters to be able to post the comment.

Comment: @Tom Mr. Skeet's first name is spelled without the 'h'.

Comment: @ChrisF - thanks, I thought it was some new-fangled Internet slang I wasn't aware of.  Damn kids.

Comment: @wai Consider it part of the 15 character stretch :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Stack Overflow so Microsoft-centric?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32516/why-is-stack-overflow-so-microsoft-centric)

Comment: @waiwai933 Yes. I always make that mistake.

Comment: @perbert, @JayRiggs Eexactly what @ChrisF said.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that a lot of SO users also read Jeff Atwood's blog, which is probably more popular in the C# community than any other, which may have to do with Jeff also being primarily a C# developer.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_Overflow&oldid=379364533#Partisanship):

> In addition to use IIS and ASP.Net Stackoverflow is a MICROSOFT partner, receiving revenues from MICROSOFT advertising. This is creating a very oriented ambiance where everything that is not benefiting MICROSOFT is systematically dismissed or censored by 'super-users' who have full-power to edit or delete the posts and accounts of other users.
>
> Jon Skeet, the Stackoverflow 'uber-user' (207k reputation), a MICROSOFT MVP (C#, 2003 onwards) and author of the book "C# in Depth", is prompt to flag anything that outdoes C# as 'SPAM' -arguing that discussing IIS using C# is legitimate and informative but that discussing a free Web server using ANSI C is "obvious advertising" (citation missing after censorship).
>
> The most obvious consequence of this selective strategy is that C# accounts for many times more questions and replies than any other topic[15].

...so *obviously* C# is gonna be over-represented when there are these "super-users" (and "uber-user") running around destroying everything else!

Comment: Aw, ya gotta be kidding me! Wikipedia says this?  Oh the horror...I'm melting, melting...What a world.

Comment: Looks like [somebody fixed it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_Overflow&oldid=379488740)  All is well with the world again.

Comment: @Shog9: If your 81.62.252.190 then that is hilarious. +1

Comment: @Dexter: not I... Sounds like someone got slapped down for spamming.

Comment: Wow... that's really sad. It's not clear whether this is someone's idea of a joke or not...

Comment: Fortunately, it only lasted about 5 hours, @uber-user

Comment: Since the vandal just rolled back the *"removed vandalism"* rollback with a comment of *"removed censhorship"*, I guess it's not meant as a joke. Sigh. At least the page itself is still at the revision before the vandalism.

Answer (score 1):

We also learn from that graph that logarithmic graphs are sometimes more appropriate, depending on the data.